# How to add extra fields in request JSON sent to DialogFlow former Api.ai

Tags: javascript, json, dialogflow-es

I am trying to append extra information to the [json](/questions/tagged/json)request that is sent from my application to `DialogFlow`. I am aware of the possibility to send data calling an intent by triggering its event from [Sending Parameters in a Query Request](https://dialogflow.com/docs/events#sending_parameters_in_a_query_request), and I am using that method already for other functionality.

Basically, I am trying to add a value with the `userID`, and I need to retrieve that value in `DialogFlow`. I am keepeing track of the session in [php](/questions/tagged/php), so I am using [php](/questions/tagged/php)to get `ID` value. I have tried to do the following in the [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)request:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: baseUrl + "query?v=20150910",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
  },
  //This folllowing line is the modified part:
  data: JSON.stringify({
    query: text,
    lang: "en",
    sessionId: "somerandomthing",
    userId: "100"
  }),
  success: function(data) {

  },
  error: function() {
    setResponse("Internal Server Error");
  }
});
```

And this one as well:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: baseUrl + "query?v=20150910",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
  },
  //This folllowing line is the modified part:
  data: JSON.stringify({
    query: text,
    lang: "en",
    sessionId: "somerandomthing",
    userId: "100",
    parameters: {
      userId: "100"
    }
  }),
  success: function(data) {

  },
  error: function() {
    setResponse("Internal Server Error");
  }
});
```

I need that value in the request to process some data in the `back-end` based on it. If anyone knows how to do it, or has suggestions for a better approach that would be much appreciated.

There are discussion posts related to this in the DialogFlow Forums, but there is still no resolution. The feature might not be available, or it is not documented [Link 1](https://discuss.api.ai/t/extra-field-in-request-json/9110?source_topic_id=13695), [Link 2](https://discuss.api.ai/t/query-with-additional-parameters-android/8201?source_topic_id=13695), [Link 3](https://discuss.api.ai/t/pass-additional-parameters-in-json-to-webhook-from-html-js-platform/6956?source_topic_id=13695).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue with the help of @Svetlana from Dialogflow. The original post is [Here](https://discuss.api.ai/t/how-to-add-extra-fields-or-parameters-in-json-request/13695), and here is an example from a JavaScript application with back-end in Node.js:

You would format your request like:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: baseUrl + "query?v=20150910",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                headers: {

                    "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
                },
                data: JSON.stringify({originalRequest: {data: {exampleMessage: 'Test'}}, query: text, lang: 'en', sessionId: 'somerandomthing'}),
                success: function (data) {

                },
                error: function () {
                    setResponse("Internal Server Error");
                }
            });
```

and you would access the value in the webhook with:

```
var exampleMessage = req.body.originalRequest.data.exampleMessage;
```

or

```
var exampleMessage = req.body.originalRequest.data['exampleMessage'];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: any idea how to do this in DialogFlow v2?

Comment: @sid8491, hi mate, that is a good question. I left the project where we were using dialogflow, but I know they removed the originalRequest field, as you can see comparing here https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-json/blob/master/requests/v1/request.json and here https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-json/blob/master/requests/v2/request.json I think it is a valid new question.