# How to wrap a chatbot created in Google's dialogflow.com in a different app?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I created a very basic and simple chatbot by Google's DialogFlow.com. DialogFlow allows us to embed the chatbot with a webpage by `<iframe>` but my intent is to use the bot for different users to track what each use may have to say. Is it possible to interact with the created chatbot by a POST request?

For e.g. when a user types in "Hello my friend" we would be able to POST it to dialogflow chatbot and get response back for that specific chat instance? If so how?

Comment: [This stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47342817/how-to-add-extra-fields-in-request-json-sent-to-dialogflow-former-api-ai) explains the details how to solve this problem.

Comment: If you're answering your own question - you can post it as an answer. If you're providing additional information, you can edit your question. It isn't clear which of the two you're doing.

Comment: @Prisoner I did already! I guess there is a bug (or behavior change) in stackoverflow keeping me from doing it.

Comment: It looks like you posted it as a comment - not as an answer.